# Put a certain character after every n words in Oracle

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I have a sentence like this :

> A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog

I want to put a comma after every 3 word :

> A quick brown , fox jumped over, the lazy dog,

Is it possible using **query** in **Oracle** ?

Comment: The fact that you tagged this `regexp-replace` suggests that you already know what you are supposed to do and just don't know how to do it.  Smells like homework.

Comment: I am unable to do that , I have tried using regexp_replace , regexp_instr ,regexp_count , but I am stuck .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`regexp_replace()` would do what you want.  Here is one rather simplistic method:

```
select regexp_replace(s, '([^ ]+[ ]+[^ ]+[ ]+[^ ]+)', '\1,')
from (select 'A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog' s from dual) x
```

Comment: Is there any way that I make the no of space dynamic ? I mean I need to put comma after every n words , n is variable

Comment: You can construct the regular expression using string operations.  If you need help with that, ask another question.